# returned null values in getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, content-management-system, groq

I am trying to return in my params the values of the `slug` and `tags` , please notice that `tags` is not an array it's just a string.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const chapters = await client.fetch(
    `*[_type == "chapters" && defined(slug.current)] {
      "slug": slug.current,
      "tags": tags
    }`
  );
  return {
    paths: chapters.map((s : any) => ({params: {slug : s.slug,tags: s.tags}})),
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

So when I try to get the `tags` value in my getStaticProps I get a null value, yet `slug` is not null.

```
export async function getStaticProps(context: any) {
  const { slug = "",tags="" } = context.params
  const suggestions = await client.fetch(`
  *[_type == "chapters" && tags == $tags][0]
`, { tags })
```

when I try to replace the `tags` value in getStaticProps with a defined value , it fetches the document successfully ,this means the `tags` value received from getStaticPaths is null.
How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: What is your chapters response?

Comment: @N.SH when I hard code the value of `tags` with an existing value , It will return all the documents that has the same `tags` value , but the returned `tags`value from getStaticPaths is null therefore I get null as a response

Comment: As I found your back end response need to check the problem because your response of your fetched api is null

Comment: How so exactly to do that ?

Comment: what is your mean of client that you called it as client.fetch?

Comment: I am using Sanity as CMS to fetch the data

Comment: can you do `console.log(chapters)` and edit your post with the value?

Comment: I'm assuming your dynamic page is `/[slug].js`, which means only `slug` can get passed in `getStaticPaths` (Next.js will ignore/drop any other parameter). If you want to have both `slug` and `tags` then you either need a route like `/[slug]/[tags].js` or, alternatively, a [dynamic catch-all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) `/[...params]`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you, as far as I know and excuse me if I'm wrong, Incremental Static Regeneration

getStaticPaths: only one params is placed in this case it could be slug

getStaticProps: the params only receive slug , if you want to place several then use query, but you will lose Incremental Static Regeneration, in a nutshell you will not be able to place getStaticPaths